# How to align text according to image inside input text filed?

Tags: css, html, css-position

[image]

```
<input type="text" class="usernm"
             style="color:black;font-weight: bold;outline-width: 0;"
             id="username" />
```

Above is my HTML code. I am trying to add icon inside the text field. But I don't know how to align text according to icon, so that both the text and icon will be center aligned. plz somebody suggest some idea to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

with css you could do something like  (I suggest to add an id to you img markup because the following will impact all your img markups)

```
.img {
    position: relative;
    top : -5 px;
}

#username {
    position: relative;
    top : -5 px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/88z953x4/1/)**

css:

```
.text_box {
    background:url('user.png') left center no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    height:30px;
    width:90%;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" value="Please enter a username" class="text_box" />
```

Updated demo with **[autocomplete](http://jsfiddle.net/ekhT4/1179/)**

Comment: I tried this method, if autocomplete is enabled in the browser, image is getting disappared. Autocomplete text is overwriting the background image. So its not working.

Comment: can you post relevant code which you tried as a demo?